# Retrieving values ​in React's useState

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem retrieving a value from the value variable in useState. The value returns 0 when saved to Mysql.

```
const [number, setnumber] = useState("");

const onChange = (event) => {
   setnumber(event.target.value); 
  };

  {billnum.map((billnums, index) => (
        <div key={index} className="mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="billnum" className="form-label">
            BillNumber
          </label>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            type="text"
            value={billnums.billnum}
            onChange={onChange}
          ></input>
        </div>
      ))}
```

I want the value from the Value obtained from the Map be save to mysql.

Comment: You also need to check the type of that field in MySQL table, it might be it accepts only numbers, but your `number` variable is a  `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem you have is with `value` property in `input` tag. You need to have  `defaultValue` in the beginning, so it will be possible to overwrite it.

You also need to check the type of that field in MySQL table, it might be it accepts only `numbers`, but your number variable is a `String`.

So, this should be good enough for you:

```
  const onChange = (event) => {
    setnumber(event.target.value);
    console.log(typeof number); // gives String

    // if you want number you can convert it
    setnumber(parseFloat(event.target.value));
  };
```

and `input` tag:

```
 <input
            className="form-control"
            type="text"
            defaultValue={billnums.billnum}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice, I did it